# After Windows reset lost my user folder where my Pycharm Projects folder was and can't recover files

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file, pycharm

I just did a reset on Windows and deleted all the files, but did not wipe my drive clean. When i realized that I didn't put my Pycharm Projects folder into onedrive I started try to recover this folder with all my code in it. I found the user folder that held my Pycharm projects folder in windows.old and when i went into the project folder it had all the logs from messing around with the code and the project foler .iml file, but did not have any of the actual .py files from my coding projects. Is there anyway to recover these files. I tried to look everywhere and have done everything I can to recover these files but nothing is doing the trick

Comment: In any case. Remember to do backups. Hard disk fails more often then people things (+ changes of OS, viruses, user errors, etc.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Windows just updated to a new verion or build, that's why moved your project to a folder called `windows.old`, you need to copy the files that you need outside, then reinstall pycharm. It's recommended to reinstall programs.

For new projects, remember to use git repositories, [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) or [www.gitlab.com](http://www.gitlab.com) can host private projects to avoid those problems